# Strategies to deal with problems when downcasting looks like the best fit

Tags: haskell, dynamic

Usually, use sum types is pretty straightforward and works very well in many cases

```
data LifeForm = Grass | Sheep | Wolf
```

but when I want open my "LifeForm" on my problems I fall in heterogeneus containers, `Data.Dynamic`, `Data.Typeable` and so on ([here a silly example using a simple String to discover the "type" at runtime](https://gist.github.com/josejuan/2f0cd749d07130c8570b40d835824ad0)).

I'll like extend my "LifeForm" in a manner that new "life forms" can interact and **restrict** between them with **their own** and new properties (classes).

Typically downcast at runtime is the simplest way in many languages.

I'm looking for useful strategies I could use to extend (without change the "core") containers when their elements may know or not optional properties of the others (eg. `class Vegetable a`, `class Runner a`, ...).

How do you deal with it?

Are [Data.MultiConstrainedDynamic](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-dynamic-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-MultiConstrainedDynamic.html) and others the best way?

Is preferable try to avoid this extensibility?

Thk!

**UPDATED** to clarify *"What's not clear at all is what you wish you could do with it. "*

Once I've my *"lifeforms core"*:

1. I like add the *"wind"* defining a new `class AffectedByTheWind a`, now any lifeform could be affected by the wind (for every *"world step"* the *"Wind life form"* will check all `AffectedByTheWind`).
2. I like add the **Dodo** bird instancing `class Fly a`, `class IsMeat a`, `class Might a`, ... and automatically other *"life forms"* can interact with it.
3. I like add a *"watcher life form"* (a *"spirit form"*) reporting how many life forms can run (instance `class Runner a`).
4. I like add a *"behavior life form"* (a *"element form"*) that check how many `IsMeat` forms exists and reduce their vital energy.
5. ...

All of this can be achieved using sum types or fixed type class hierarchy but is not extensible in the *"expression problem"* sense.

Comment: One way (much frowned upon) is existential types. Another one (better regarded but ultimately equivalent to the former) is storing manually assembled method dictionaries. These correspond not to downcasts but to virtual functions/late bound methods in OO.

Comment: I find such questions usually can't be answered well in Haskell without more details about what you want to represent and what directions you want to generalize in.

Comment: You may or may not find inspiration in https://userpages.uni-koblenz.de/~laemmel/TheEagle/ and http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/

Comment: @dfeuer I think my example is pretty clear (LifeForms) if you have some example closed to it, will be great!

Comment: Your LifeForm data type is perfectly clear indeed. What's not clear at all is what you wish you could do with it.

Comment: Why not create separate types and make all of them an instance of `class LifeForm`? You can then choose to appropriate instances for every data type / newtype as you need.

Comment: ... I don't what you want. If you want an extensible `LifeForm` then make `LifeForm` a class and *not* a data type...

Comment: @Bakuriu, can you provide some example?